# Create an array with NULL values/0 and find array length excluding null/0

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I want to find the number of columns in a range in each row which has non-null and >0 value.

I have done this currently using `case when` statements or `IF-ELSE`. But the number of columns that i have to now consider has increased and with that the number of case statements too.

So i wanted to create an `array` of the columns and then find the `length` of the array after excluding `0` and `NULL` values.

I tried the follow code but i am getting an error

```
**case1**
SELECT [col1,col2,col3,col4,col5] from input_Table

Error: Array cannot have a null element; error in writing field

**case2**
SELECT *,
  ARRAY(SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
        from input_table
        WHERE col1 is not null and col2 is not null ...) 
from input_Table

Error: ARRAY subquery cannot have more than one column unless using SELECT AS STRUCT to build STRUCT values at [2:3]
```

Below is a snapshot of my data
[image]

The output that i want is

```
1
2
0
```

It would be super helpful if somebody can help me with this, I am very new to Bigquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to find the number of columns in a range in each row which has non-null and >0 value ...

**Option 1**

Below is for BigQuery and generic enough to work for any number of columns

```
SELECT *,
  (SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(
        TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"col\d+":(.*?)[,}]')     
      ) value
    WHERE NOT value IN ('null', '0')
  ) AS non_null_0_count
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

Above assumes pattern for columns as col1, col2, .., colNN

You can test , play with above using dummy data from your question as in below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 col1, 0 col2, 0 col3, 0 col4, 0 col5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
)
SELECT *,
  (SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(
        TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"col\d+":(.*?)[,}]')     
      ) value
    WHERE NOT value IN ('null', '0')
  ) AS non_null_0_count
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

with result

```
Row id  col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    non_null_0_count     
1   1   1       0       0       0       0       1    
2   2   4       5       0       0       0       2    
3   3   null    null    null    null    null    0
```

**Option 2**

In case if above mentioned column pattern is not really a case - this approach still works - see example below  - you just need to enumerate those columns within regexp

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 abc, 0 xyz, 0 qwe, 0 asd, 0 zxc UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
)
SELECT *,
  (SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(
        TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"(?:abc|xyz|qwe|asd|zxc)":(.*?)[,}]')
      ) value
    WHERE NOT value IN ('null', '0') 
  ) AS non_null_0_count
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

with result as

```
Row id  abc     xyz     qwe     asd     zxc     non_null_0_count     
1   1   1       0       0       0       0       1    
2   2   4       5       0       0       0       2    
3   3   null    null    null    null    null    0
```

**Option 3**

Obviously, the most simple and straightforward option is

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(1)
    FROM (
      SELECT col1 col UNION ALL 
      SELECT col2 UNION ALL 
      SELECT col3 UNION ALL 
      SELECT col4 UNION ALL 
      SELECT col5
    )
    WHERE NOT col IS NULL AND col != 0
  ) AS non_null_0_count
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is to simply use `case` -- because you know the number of columns:

```
select id,
       (case when col1 = 0 or col1 is null then 0
             when col2 = 0 or col2 is null then 1
             when col3 = 0 or col3 is null then 2
             when col4 = 0 or col4 is null then 3
             when col5 = 0 or col5 is null then 4
             else 5
        end) as result             
from t;
```

Although can do fancy manipulations with arrays, I don't see a need for this, given that the number of columns is finite and the `case` expression is pretty simple.